# add a new column to a serie pandas with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called 'erm' like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSklA.png)

I would like to add a new column 'typeRappel' xith value = 1 if erm['Calcul'] has value 4.
This is my code:

```
# IF ( calcul = 4 ) TypeRappel = 1.
# erm.loc[erm.Calcul = 4, "typeRappel"] = 1
#erm["typeRappel"] = np.where(erm['Calcul'] = 4.0, 1, 0)
# erm["Terminal"] = ["1" if c = "010" for c in erm['Code']]
# erm['typeRappel'] = [ 1 if x == 4 for x in erm['Calcul']]

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

erm['typeRappel'] = [ 1 if x == 4 for x in erm['Calcul']]
```

But this code send me an error like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56fvc.png)

What can be the problem ??

```
# IF ( calcul = 4 ) TypeRappel = 1.
# erm.loc[erm.Calcul = 4, "typeRappel"] = 1
#erm["typeRappel"] = np.where(erm['Calcul'] = 4.0, 1, 0)
# erm["Terminal"] = ["1" if c = "010" for c in erm['Code']]
# erm['typeRappel'] = [ 1 if x == 4 for x in erm['Calcul']]

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

erm['typeRappel'] = [ 1 if x == 4 for x in erm['Calcul']]
```

Comment: Unsure why the syntax error is pointing to the `=`, but you're going to run into issues with the list comprehension if you don't have an `else` statement after the `if`. Could you try `erm['typeRappel'] = None`? Just want to isolate what the potential issue could be.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want using `lambda`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[[1,2],[4,5],[7,8],[4,11]],
    columns=['Calcul','other_col']
)
df['typeRappel'] = df['Calcul'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == 4 else None)
```

This results in

| Calcul | other_col | typeRappel |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | NaN |
| 4 | 5 | 1.0 |
| 7 | 8 | NaN |
| 4 | 11 | 1.0 |

Comment: It's also workw sir @Paulo Coelho Kotchetkoff . Thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 way for this

**first way:**

use from .loc method because you have just 1 condition

```py
df['new']=None
df.loc[df.calcul.eq(4), 'new'] =1
```

**Second way:**
use from numpy.select method

```py
import numpy as np
cond=[df.calcul.eq(4)]
df['new']= np.select(cond, [1], None)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#erm['typeRappel']=None
erm.loc[erm.Calcul.eq(4), 'typeRappel'] = 1

import numpy as np
cond=[erm.Calcul.eq(4)]
erm['ok']= np.select(cond, [1], None)
```